# Restore browser scroll position without forcing layout or scroll flickering

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there a way to restore scroll position without forcing layout?

If done too early
`elem.scrollTo({ left, top, behavior: 'instant' })` forces layout. If done too late one gets scroll flickering.

[Minimal reproduction in a React app](https://github.com/mstewartgallus/scrollto-slow)

Important Code.

Stuff like throttling `onScroll` or saving to session storage isn't done here.

`scrollTo` consistently forces layout and there doesn't seem to an appropriate workaround.

```
import { useCallback, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";
import './Scroller.css';

const scroll = new Map();

const Scroller = ({children}) => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const onScroll = useCallback(e => {
        const { target } = e;
        // FIXME throttle
        const { scrollLeft, scrollTop } = target;
        scroll.set(pathname, { scrollLeft, scrollTop });
    }, [pathname]);

    const ref = useRef(null);
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const state = scroll.get(pathname) ?? { scrollLeft: 0, scrollTop: 0 };
        const { scrollLeft: left, scrollTop: top } = state;
        ref.current.scrollTo({ left, top, behavior: 'instant' });
    }, [pathname]);
    return <div className="Scroller" onScroll={onScroll} ref={ref}>
               {children}
           </div>;
};

export default Scroller;
```

```
.Scroller {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flow-root;
    contain: layout size style paint;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.Scroller {
    padding-inline: 2em;
    padding-block: 2em;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you provide a reproducible version of the issue?

Comment: @CristóbalDíazÁlvarez when transitioning between pages in a single page app and manually managing scroll restoration when on loading a new page you use `scrollTo` and set the scroll position it forces layout causing slightly jankier page transitions.

Comment: I think this is a very puntual issue, also depending on framework of SPA an hydration configuration. Impossible to know without reproducible code example.